# jQuery button to remove parent div class, and hide itself simultaneously using hide() not working

Tags: jquery

I have a div expanding to fullscreen on click, and upon doing so a "close" button appears. On click of the close button, I want the div to return to its normal state and the button disappears. Why is the following code not working?

```js
$("#SaveNClose").hide(); // Hide the close button

$('#myDiv').click(function(e) {
  $(this).addClass('fullscreen');
  $("#SaveNClose").show();
});


$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#SaveNClose").click(function() {
    $("#myDiv").removeClass("fullscreen");
    $("#SaveNClose").hide();
  });
});
```

```css
#SaveNClose {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.myDiv.fullscreen {
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #799C4B;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="myDiv" id="myDiv">
  <button id="SaveNClose">&times Click to Save and Close</button>
  <div class="row">Main Text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why is the following code not working?

### The cause:

The "close" code is working, unfortunately it's re-maximising (running the myDiv fullscreen) immediately after closing - so the appearance is that nothing happens.

A little bit of debugging shows what's happening:

```js
$("#SaveNClose").hide(); // Hide the close button

$('#myDiv').click(function(e) {
  console.log("mydiv click")
  $(this).addClass('fullscreen');
  $("#SaveNClose").show();
});


$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#SaveNClose").click(function() {
    console.log("close click")
    $("#myDiv").removeClass("fullscreen");
    $("#SaveNClose").hide();
  });
});
```

```css
#SaveNClose {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.myDiv.fullscreen {
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #799C4B;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="myDiv" id="myDiv">
  <button id="SaveNClose">&times Click to Save and Close</button>
  <div class="row">Main Text</div>
</div>
```

When you click the close, the close is *inside* myDiv so myDiv *also* gets that same click event as click events *propagate* up to parents.

## The Fix

You need to stop the close event from propagating up to the parent div.  There's various ways to do this, the easiest is to add:

```
return false;
```

to the end of your event handler.  Another is `event.stopPropagation()` - see [jquery stopPropagation](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

Updated snippet with one line changed:

```js
$("#SaveNClose").hide(); // Hide the close button

$('#myDiv').click( function(e)
  {
  $(this).addClass('fullscreen');
  $("#SaveNClose").show();
  });
$(document).ready( function() 
  {
  $("#SaveNClose").click( function() 
    {
    $("#myDiv").removeClass("fullscreen");
    $("#SaveNClose").hide();
    
    return false;
    });
  });
```

```css
#SaveNClose
  {
  border           : 1px solid black;
  background-color : red;
  border-radius    : 50px;
  padding-left     : 10px;
  padding-right    : 10px;
  padding-top      : 5px;
  padding-bottom   : 5px;
  }
.myDiv.fullscreen 
  {
  z-index          : 9999;
  width            : 100%;
  height           : 100%;
  position         : fixed;
  text-align       : center;
  align-items      : center;
  top              : 0;
  left             : 0;
  background-color : #799C4B;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="myDiv" id="myDiv">
  <button id="SaveNClose">
    &times Click to Save and Close
  </button>
  <div class="row">
    Main Text
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've modified your code a little bit in order to separate the div which receives the click event and the div which renders full size.

```js
$("#SaveNClose").hide(); // Hide the close button

$('#myDivInner').click(function(e) {
  $('#myDiv').addClass('fullscreen');
  $("#SaveNClose").show();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#SaveNClose").click(function() {
    $("#myDiv").removeClass("fullscreen");
    $("#SaveNClose").hide();
  });
});
```

```css
#SaveNClose {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.myDiv.fullscreen {
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #799C4B;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="myDiv" id="myDiv">
  <button id="SaveNClose">&times Click to Save and Close</button>
  <div class="myDiv" id="myDivInner">
    <div class="row">Main Text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @wing22yu you should mark response as accepted answer